# Orchard returns page not found

Tags: error-handling, orchardcms

I am new to Orchard CMS. I have a requirement to create an email notification to the admin  if there is any error. I have made a custom module so it would send an email to admin. Also, I have put a redirection to the module from error page.

here is my code in `NotFound.cshtml` in my custom theme

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function ToError() {
        window.location.href = '/FourOFour?LastURL=' +
            (window.location.host + window.location.pathname);
    }
    window.onload = ToError;
</script>
```

here is my custom route in the module I create

```
new RouteDescriptor {
    Priority = 11,
    Route = new Route(
        "FourOFour",
        new RouteValueDictionary {
            {"area", "Prenagen.ErrorEmailing"},
            {"controller","Utama"},
            {"action","Error404"}
        },
        new RouteValueDictionary(),
        new RouteValueDictionary{
            {"area", "Prenagen.ErrorEmailing"}
        },
        new MvcRouteHandler())
}
```

So the not found page will redirect to `/FourOFour`. When I test it in localhost, all things works fine. I type a non-exist page and it redirect to `NotFound` then to `/FourOFour?LastURL=page`. And the email is sent to the admin. When I publish it to server, the not found redirect to FourOFour, but the page is not found. How can I solve this? Please, anyone help me.

edit: It creates an infinite loop because `FourOFour` is not found and it keeps redirecting to the same page.

Comment: Maybe you didn't enable your module?

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy The module has been enabled already in local and server. But still that FourOFour page returns `Not Found`. The view is not the problem too, because I have create the view in my custom theme and module.

Comment: Can you confirm that "Prenagen.ErrorEmailing" is the name of your project, the name of the module in module.txt, and the name of the folder that contains your module in the modules folder?  I seem to have trouble if I don't keep these things consistent.

Comment: A few remarks that are not directly related to the question asked but that the code raises... Redirecting 404s is a bad idea: the user can't look at the url he typed and self-correct. Redirecting in Javascript is a bad idea: it won't work for clients without JS, and server redirects work just fine, so why bother? Finally, I'm wondering if Log4Net, the logging library used by Orchard, could not natively catch 404s and send e-mails with some configuration modifications.

Comment: @BrandonJoyce yes, it is the name of the project and the module and it is described so in the `module.txt` file.

@BertrandLeRoy so if there is any 404 error I can redirect to a certain location? how to do so? if that can i will surely choose that way.

Answer (score 1):

Is your dynamic compilation disabled?

If it is and you've copied only the files that you've changed this can be the cause of your problems.

The other thing that might be the cause of your problems is if the changes you've made required creation of new files that were added to the project. If that was the case, you should have also copied .csproj file to the server to instruct Orchard to include the newly added files in dynamic compilation.

Try to rebuild your module in release mode and copy the whole module to the server instead of only the files that you've changed and see if that works..

Comment: how can I check the dynamic compilation?

Comment: It is disabled by default if you don't upload .csproj file with the module. It can also be disabled with the procedure described in documentation (http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Orchard-module-loader-and-dynamic-compilation#Disablingthe"DynamicModule"loader). I think I read somewhere that in Orchard 1.6 this will be disabled by default (or they may have said that it's planned for some of the future versions).

Comment: if it's disabled, make sure that you uploaded the whole `/bin` folder of the module..

Comment: so I've just disabled it. I will republish the web to server now. Also, Is the `/bin` folder that you mean was the one in `Orchard.Web\bin`? Because I have uploaded it. And also I compare the content and there is no difference.